# SQL Server 2008 Stored Procedure Using Merge

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a `merge` statement in a stored procedure like this:

```
Alter procedure [dbo].[InsertMultipleFruits]
(
    @FruitCrates As Fruits_CratesType READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @I INT;

    MERGE INTO Fruits_Crates AS TARGET
    USING (SELECT FruitID, CrateID FROM @FruitCrates) AS SOURCE
        ON (TARGET.FruitID = SOURCE.FruitID AND TARGET.CrateID = SOURCE.CrateID)

    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE 
            SET @I = 1  --- I want nothing to happen here ---

    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT (FruitID, CrateID)
        VALUES (SOURCE.FruitID, SOURCE.CrateID)

    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
        DELETE;
END;
```

**Problem**

If I have this record in table:

```
CrateID        FruitID
1              4
```

Then if I send parameter with  `CrateID = 2` and `FruitID = 4`, I want it to add another row but it just replaces it and show this,

```
CrateID        FruitID
2              4
```

I want when updating is, delete all records where CrateID = 2 and then add new records I am sending in parameter, don't touch another CrateIDs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about the overall operation that you are trying to perform, it is really just a Wipe-and-Replace based on what you are passing in. According to your stated rules:

- if I send parameter with  CrateID = 2 and FruitID = 4, I want it to add another row (*assumption is that no rows exist yet for CrateID = 2*)
- if rows already exist for CrateID = 2: delete all records where CrateID = 2 and then add new records I am sending in parameter, don't touch another CrateIDs

Hence, you shouldn't be using `MERGE` for this.  Instead, just do:

```sql
DELETE fc
FROM Fruits_Crates fc
WHERE fc.CrateID IN (SELECT DISTINCT tmp.CrateID FROM #FruitCrates tmp);

INSERT INTO Fruits_Crates (FruitID, CrateID)
   SELECT tmp.FruitID, tmp.CrateID
   FROM FruitCrates tmp;
```

Or, if most of the time the number of items that match exceeds the number of items that will be removed and added, you can take a more targeted approach:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #FruitCrates (FruitID INT, CrateID INT);
CREATE TABLE #Fruits_Crates (FruitID INT, CrateID INT);

--DELETE FROM #FruitCrates
INSERT INTO #FruitCrates (CrateID, FruitID) VALUES (2, 4);
INSERT INTO #FruitCrates (CrateID, FruitID) VALUES (2, 6);
INSERT INTO #FruitCrates (CrateID, FruitID) VALUES (3, 26);

--DELETE FROM #Fruits_Crates;
INSERT INTO #Fruits_Crates (CrateID, FruitID) VALUES (1, 4);
INSERT INTO #Fruits_Crates (CrateID, FruitID) VALUES (2, 4);
INSERT INTO #Fruits_Crates (CrateID, FruitID) VALUES (2, 8);

DELETE fc
--SELECT fc.*, '--' AS [--], tmp.*
FROM #Fruits_Crates fc
LEFT JOIN #FruitCrates tmp
       ON tmp.CrateID = fc.CrateID
      AND tmp.FruitID = fc.FruitID
WHERE tmp.CrateID IS NULL
AND   fc.CrateID IN (SELECT DISTINCT tmp2.CrateID FROM #FruitCrates tmp2);

INSERT INTO #Fruits_Crates (FruitID, CrateID)
   SELECT tmp.FruitID, tmp.CrateID
   FROM #FruitCrates tmp
   LEFT JOIN #Fruits_Crates fc
          ON fc.CrateID = tmp.CrateID
         AND fc.FruitID = tmp.FruitID
   WHERE fc.CrateID IS NULL;

SELECT CrateID, FruitID FROM #Fruits_Crates;
```

Output:

```
CrateID  FruitID
1        4
2        4
2        6
3        26
```

Result:

- Row with CrateID = 1, FruitID = 4: **left alone**
- Row with CrateID = 2, FruitID = 4: **left alone**
- Row with CrateID = 2, FruitID = 8: **removed**
- Row with CrateID = 2, FruitID = 6: **added**
- Row with CrateID = 3, FruitID = 26: **added**

Answer (score 1):

Your script doesn't replace, it creates a new row and deletes the old row.

You could simply do a conditional insert. But using a merge, you can try this instead:

```
Alter procedure [dbo].[InsertMultipleFruits]
(
    @FruitCrates As Fruits_CratesType READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @I INT;

    DELETE t1
    FROM Fruits_Crates t1
    LEFT JOIN @FruitCrates t2
    ON t1.FruitID = t2.FruitID
    WHERE t2.FruitID is null


    ;MERGE INTO Fruits_Crates AS TARGET
    USING (SELECT FruitID, CrateID FROM @FruitCrates) AS SOURCE
        ON (TARGET.FruitID = SOURCE.FruitID AND TARGET.CrateID = SOURCE.CrateID)

    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE 
            SET @I = 1  --- I want nothing to happen here ---

    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT (FruitID, CrateID)
        VALUES (SOURCE.FruitID, SOURCE.CrateID);

-- This was always deleting rows that didn't match
--    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
--        DELETE;


END
```